# performance analysis of multiple platforms

Tags: multithreading, profiling, benchmarking, code-analysis

I have written a Program that runs in two modes,Sequential and Multithreaded,with the purpose of running it on multiple processor architectures and then analyzing the processors' performance and comparing them.

are there any tools that can help me do that ?? find execution time,track threads and their preemption,find which processor executed which thread(if on a multicore system),the context switching overhead and other stuff.

I already have basic knowledge about code profiling with gprof and i believe it is not sufficient for that matter. I'm searching for something that is the same idea but a lot more powerful !! 
any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more information on the execution time, cache behavior, etc. there are various approaches. Make sure to create a stable compute environment first. Lock the processor frequency to get reliable measurements, e.g. in the BIOS disable Intel SpeedStep; avoid any background processes, etc.

Low-level performance counters:

- You can instrument your code with high-resolution counters and measure performance. Take a look at the [PAPI interface for performance measurement](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/).

Advanced profilers:

- [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org), open source. Perf does a sample-based measurement and shows various profiling information, with full support for multiple threads. For instance the Perf Flamegraph gives a very good overview of hotspots in your code.
- Intel VTune, commercial. Will show you detailed cache statistics from HW counters, performance per thread, etc. Requires quite some insight in the hardware to interpret the data.

Note that all the above can also measure power consumption.

Alternatively, you can have a look at the behavior of your program over time, by creating a trace of thread switches in the OS. Have a look at Eclipse's LTTng integration.

If you want to see more information on the actual parallel behavior of your code, such as data dependencies that may inhibit parallelism, thread overhead and cache contention, you could have a go at Pareon from Vector Fabrics (disclaimer: I am one of the founders of Vector Fabrics). This is not a profiler, but more code analysis for parallelization.